# How to access image resources in JEE6 project?

Tags: java, image, jsf, resources, jakarta-ee

I have to doubts regarding to calling images that are stored in my project:

1-If i have an image stored at MyApp/images/image.gif

How can i tell the component h:graphicImage to find that image?
I tried this but it didn't work

```
<h:graphicImage value="MyApp/images/image.gif"/>
```

2- I am interested in knowing how to call images that are  stored under WEB-INF/images
I read somewhere that I need a servlet for that because cannot be accessed directly.

Is that true? How can i do that?

**Update**

This is a print screen of my projectStructure, so you can see where are the files where i need to access.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a summary of the cause of you issue:

- A browser loads each image by sending an HTTP request for the resource.
- Resources that are under the WEB-INF directory can not be directly retrieved via an HTTP request.

You have several options:

1. Move the images directory such that it is under the WebContent directory, but is not under the WEB-INf directory.  For example, *WebContent/images*
2. Intercept requests for images in a servlet or filter, read the file from within the servlet or filter, then return the file.  There are 3rd party implementations of this.  I like the Spring ResourceServlet class; if nothing else, it will demonstrate this technique (it is open source, so you can just read the code if you like).

Comment: Move the directories "images" and "templates" into the directory "WebContent"